# How to implement an onboarding page with Prism.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I am developing a *Xamarin.Forms* app with *Prism* in which I'd like to incorporate an onboarding page (more specific a top user benefits page, following the [Material Design guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/growth-communications/onboarding.html#onboarding-quickstart)).

The app itself is structured around a `NavigationPage` to which I navigate with

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationRootPage/MainPage")
```

in my `App()`. On the first start I'd like to show the onboarding page instead and I am having quite some issues getting it right.

My **first approach** was to navigate to `MainPage` with

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationRootPage/MainPage")
```

from my viewmodel, when the user clicks the *Get Started!* button. This kind of worked by is also kind of ugly, since this absolute navigation will destroy the oboarding page immediately and not animate the transition. Furthermore at the moment the oboarding page is destroyed, the `MainPage` will be built, which will take a small, but noticeable, amount of time. In effect the user will notice the `MainPage` being built up, which does not look smooth at all.

My **second approach** was to navigate in a relative fashion from my viewmodel.

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationRootPage/MainPage")
```

This works way smoother, with the transition animation and after the animation is done, the `MainPage` is already ready to go. But again there is a major drawback. You can navigate back to the onbaording page, which we dont't want neither. And - to my knowledge - there is no (clean) way to remove the page from the navigation stack, too. I tried calling `PageUtility.DestroyPage` on my onboarding page, but this only worsened things, since it seemed to keep the page, but destroy the viewmodel, resulting in my onboarding page being shown without data when pushing the back button.

My *third approach* did not work at all, although it seemed promising to me. In my `App()` I pushed my navigation page with the main page then then my onboarding page modal

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("/NavigationRootPage/MainPage");
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("OnboardingPage", useModalNavigation: true);
```

and then in my viewmodel

```
_navigationService.GoBackAsync(useModalNavigation: true)
```

but this approach

- showed the header of the `NavigationPage` although the onbaording page was supposed to be shown as a modal
- refused to `GoBackAsync` - when calling this method, nothing happens

waiting for the first call to `NavigateAsync` did not change anything either.

Some **other things** I've tried

- Implemented `INavigationOptions` in my viewmodel with `ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation` being `true`
- Tried setting `Application.MainPage` after my `NavigationPage` was shown, but to no avail

I would have believed that this was king of a common requirement when programming an app. Is there something I've missed? Or will I have to live with one of those drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking this.  If you want to show your Onborading page first then just navigate to it first.

`NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/OnboardingPage");

Or if you want to have the MainPage in the stack, then start the app with a deeplink

`NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage/OnboardingPage");

If you don't want to show the navigation header, just hide it for the onboarding page.

Don't use an absolute navigation unless you want to completely reset the navigation stack (equivalent to `MainPage = new MainPage()`).

Comment: I *may* have overthought this ;) Works like a charm, but I still wonder why I can't close a modal with `GoBackAsync`

Comment: I think this also solves another issue I was just about to tackle. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I **have** found a solution, which is not the most beautiful one (it is actually quite ugly) but working.

In my `MainPage`s viewmodel I implemented `INavigatingAware` and navigated to my `OnboardingPage` modally

```
public async void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("LandingPage", useModalNavigation: true);
}
```

However, removing the moal page with

```
this._navigationService.GoBackAsync(useModalNavigation: true);
```

does not work as expected. The modal is not removed (although it should work this way from looking at the code, but I did not manage to debug with Re# generated PDBs). Hence I had to go the ugly (non-MVVM) way and create an event handler for `Button.Click` and remove the modal manually

```
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

This will return to my `MainPage` smoothly with an animation and my `MainPage`is already up and running without being built up while already visible.

Still, I'd appreciate an answer on how to do it the *Prism* way.